# How to write binary data to file

Tags: node.js

I tried to write a png binary data to file use the following code but that will unable open the png file, do I have something wrong? I tried very long time, could you help me solve ?

```
fs.writeFile('myPngFile.png', new Buffer(myPngStringData, 'binary'), function (error) {
    if (error) {
        consoler.log('Error');
        return;
    }
    consoler.log('Success');
});
```

Comment: tell us more about your myPngStringData

Comment: ... and what you have tried.

Comment: the myPngStringData is a part of json response (response.body) from a third-part API, it is string type and is binary.

Comment: You claim it's binary but I have my doubts. Have you had a look in the output file? It's probably encoded somehow.

Comment: i had print it i sure it is binary data but...i don't know how to write to file

Comment: can u help me look at this "Download the converted file" of API DOC https://developers.zamzar.com/docs i trying to write that response.body to my file but always failed.

Comment: Can you post a piece of the binary data? Since JSON doesn't support binary data, I have to concur with @tadman in that it's most likely encoded somehow (base64 or hex, probably).